# Sharepoint Online (365) Programmatically working with Managed Metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, taxonomy, office-365

So, you want to migrate some documents that have managed metadata columns from another source into SharePoint Online.

Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy is blocked.

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy is 2013 only?

...and other remote ways are blocked for various reasons.

I was thinking possibly something like:

```
item["Country"] = "-1;#" + strCountryTag;
item["f80750f091f94eed8a5edc234d010620"] = getTermWithGuid(strCountryTag, "Country");
item.Update();
```

Like you would with the client object model, but this doesn't work like this. (-1 is because the taxonomy hidden list is empty so I don't need to look up WSSIDs)

Does anyone know of something that will make the code work in the example, so you can use Managed Metadata fields like you would a standard 2010 installation just with a custom bit of code?

Please presume that all the term guids are accessible at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Country column has to be updated in this form: `<WssId>;#<Label>|<TermGuid>` and the
linked, hidden text field has to be updated with `<Label>|<TermGuid>`

`<WssId>` should be an index in the TaxonomyHiddenList if the term exists in that list, but passing -1 seems to work too.

This works on the SP2013 version of Office365, and on-premise SP2010 and SP2013.

[This MSDN blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdev/how-to-work-with-managed-metadata-columns-by-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model-kaushalendra-kumar) has more details.

Comment: That didn't work. Also getTermWithGuid does format it correctly. But it still won't update regardless.

Comment: Could you please double check that you have the right Guid? Do this by starting fiddler and editing the properties of an item with a taxonomy column. When you type and the term the autocompletion has found a term, look at the last call to  /_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json/GetSuggestions. Open the JSON tab and look at d.Groups.Suggestions and verify that your DefaultLabel and Id match the ones you use in getTermWithGuid(). Is this SP2010?

Comment: Yes, all the guids are correct. and there is an easier way, request a document in office and look at the cached xml folder, it stores the metadata locally for you. It just doesn't update the field when trying to enter the data as you suggested or any other way I tried.

Comment: But you did give myself an idea just now. If office can update the Managed Metadata I can just rip it's method off with fiddler2 :) sending you 10pt for reminding me about fiddler, I was going to run it on a migration tool and see how it did it, but there is no need. Office does it.

Comment: Thanks. But, you're right, I can't get it to work on Office365 either. (the developer preview - based on SP2013; are you using the 2010 version of Office365?). It does work on the on-prem versions of 2010 and 2013. While trying this out I also noticed you don't have to provide the -1;# (WssId).

Comment: Yeah, but I think I have it working with frontpage rpc now, it's going to be next week before I'm done. I duplicated how office deals with it. But I will persist with web services. Only a few months left until Client.Taxonomy anyway.

Comment: Updated the answer, the hidden linked text field does have to be updated, but with a different string... I wasn't able to test it in the current version of Office365, but it works in the preview of the 2013 (preview) version.

Comment: I will retest that, I'm sure I put it in like that as well with a wssid of -1, but can't test at moment might be a day or two.

Comment: I have this working now with the wssid of -1 in 365 from code behind.

Comment: @ErikE thanks for spotting the mistake; that was a bug in my script and it's now fixed :)